# How to Launch Asynchronous Record Triggered Flow each time a Date Field is updated

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, asynchronous

I have a date field. I want to update the record every time this field is updated.  Inside of the Record Triggered Flow I have an ISCHANGED condition and am seeing the following error when I try to activate the flow:

```
For a path that runs asynchronously, configure the flow to run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements or select the Is Changed operator in a condition.
```

Now, I need this flow to run asynchronously and I need to make sure that I can have dynamic logic that does not require me to insert a static DateTime field. I cannot have this because then I would have to update this daily to today's date.

How can I launch this flow asynchronously using a date field as my condition logic without having to hard code a static date in the conditions for launching the record-triggered flow?