# How to set entry criteria for After Update Record Triggered Flow with async path to fire on any/all updates?

Tags: visual-workflow

We want to create an Asynchronous path on our Account - After Update Record Triggered Flow. In order to do so, we must specify entry criteria identifying what changed before the system will enter into that Flow. If not, this error will occur when saving the Flow:

[image]

We are using Record Trigger after update Flows as a dispatcher to call other subflows. However, we'd prefer to use something like `LastModifiedDate` or `SystemModstamp` so that any/all record updates enter this Record Trigger Flow, including the Asynchronous Path. We have found that using `LastModifiedDate` and `SystemModstamp` in the Start entry criteria do not result in the Flow firing. Perhaps these fields are not updated yet when the system evaluates them to enter the Flow. So, does anything have any suggestions on how we can cause the system to enter the Flow to enter on any/all record updates?

Thank you.

Comment: why use any criteria at all? Just choose `None`

Comment: @cropredy we tried that, but apparently one must specify criteria to enable an async path on an after update record trigger flow.

Comment: Can you use a formula that evaluates to TRUE?

Comment: @cropredy thanks for the suggestion, but this does not work. I added some more detail related to my question regarding this.

Comment: Well - hack city - a before save flow that increments a Counter__c field by 1 should allow you to use an Is Changed operator in the after save flow.  But my suggestion seems prima facie silly.

Comment: [related (and unanswered)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362407/how-to-launch-asynchronous-record-triggered-flow-each-time-a-date-field-is-updat)

Comment: @cropredy thanks for the suggestion. I took this down to a simple example and it actually works! :) The immediate path runs, but for some reason, the async path gets queued and right before it executes, the scheduled date gets changed, adding 5 minutes or so each time I check in Time-based Workflow. Strange.

Comment: Related question posted here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383795/time-based-workflow-schedule-date-keeps-getting-pushed-forward-5-minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me once the Account was created, every change thereafter to the Account caused a Chatter message

[image]

entry conditions `Last Modified Date Is Changed TRUE`
[image]