# Time-based Workflow Schedule Date keeps getting pushed forward 5 minutes

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, asynchronous, recordtriggeredflow

I created a record triggered after update flow that tests if a field has changed in the entry criteria, allowing me to create an async path:

[image]

When a record is updated, the immediate path executes, well, immediately. However, the async path gets queued and I can see the workflow by looking at the Time-based Workflow queue in Salesforce:

[image]

The strange thing is, the Time-based Workflow never executes. When the scheduled date/time arrives, Salesforce changes the scheduled date/time to about 5 more minutes in the future. I've been watching this happen for about 1 hour now and cannot figure out why the work is not executing.

Comment: Having observed this myself just yesterday, the issue is there's an exception in the async path Salesforce reschedules the async for + n minutes on the hope the issue is transient or, you are able to fix the issue.  In my case, the async path was calling an invocable apex that used SOQL and I forgot to include a field needed later in the apex logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is there's an exception in the async path.

Salesforce reschedules the async for + n minutes on the hope the issue is transient or, you are able to fix the issue.

I've seen a couple of failure uses cases:

- The async path was calling an invocable apex that used SOQL and I forgot to include a field needed later in the apex logic
- A non-async scheduled path had a logic error that was not caught by debugging.

Regardless, you should get a Flow exception email when the async (or scheduled) path occurs outlining the details.